# Kudan: memory release issue of ARCameraViewController

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, kudan

I am using Kudan AR framework https://www.kudan.eu/ to develop iPhone app on Xcode 7.3.1.

I use segue to travel around different ARCameraViewControllers. I find that the memory used goes up every time segueing to a new ARCameraViewController.

Is it possible to kill the previous view　controllers manually? (to release memory)

Answer (score 0):

Kudan is working on a new version of the framework to fix this issue. In the meantime, if you're using arbiTrack, you can call [arbiTrack stop] in ViewWillDisappear, which may fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you! I do have some arbiTrack and they work fine. But the segue ones cannot be solved anyway..